# If $T$ is a nilpotent operator of order $m$, is it necessarily $dim(Im(T))=m-1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, nilpotence

I'm reading a proof of the *Nilpotent Splitting Theorem* (which states that given a nilpotent operator $T$ of order $m$ and a vector $x\in V$ such that $T^{m-1}x\not=0$, then there exists a direct complement of the span of the set $\lbrace Tx,\ldots T^{m-1}x\rbrace$, which is T-invariant).
At one point it asserts that *it is clear* that the set $\lbrace Tx,\ldots T^{m-1}x\rbrace$ spans $Im(T)$, but I can't see why this must be true. I know that set is linearly independent and obviously it is included in $Im(T)$, so it would be enough to show that $dim(Im(T))<m$.
Why is this true? I couldn't arrive at a contradiction by assuming the 
opposite.

Added:

> The Nilpotent-Splitting Theorem:
>   Suppose $V$ is a real or complex vector
>   space (not necessarily finite dimensional), and $T ∈ L(V)$ is nilpotent of index $m$. Let
>   $x$ be a vector in $V$ with $T^{m−1}x \not= 0$. Let $V_1$ be the span of the list $(x, T x, . . . , T^{m−1}x)$
>   (so $V_1$ is T-invariant). Then there is a subspace $W_1$ of V that is T-invariant, such
>   that $V = V_1 ⊕ W_1$.

Proof:

> The proof proceeds by induction on m, the index of nilpotence.
>   The case $m = 1$. In this case $T$ is the zero-operator on $V$ , so $x$ is any non-zero
>   vector in $V$ , $V_1$ = span (x), and we can take $W_1$ to be any subspace of $V$ that is
>   complementary to $V_1$ (every subspace of V is invariant for the zero-operator).
>   The Induction Hypothesis. Suppose $m > 1$ and suppose the result is true for all
>   operators that are nilpotent of index $m − 1$. The proof now proceeds in four steps.
>   Step I: Pushing Down. We focus on $ran(T)$, which you can easily check is an invariant
>   subspace for $T$ on which $T$ is nilpotent of index $m−1$, and which is clearly the span of
>   the linearly independent list $(T x,... ,T^{m−1}x)=(y, ... ,T^{m−2}y)$, where $y = T x$.
>   So we may apply the induction hypothesis to the restriction of T to ran T, with $V_1$
>   replaced by the subspace
>   $Y_1 = span (y, ... ,T^{m−2}
> y)$.
>   The result is a T-invariant subspace $Y_2$ of $ran (T)$ such that
>   $ran(T) = Y_1 ⊕ Y_2$

And the proof keeps on.

Comment: We're missing some information here.  Is $m = \dim(V)$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No, $V$ does not even need to be finite dimensional (according to the statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, the claim is false.  For example, take
$$
T = \pmatrix{0&1\\&0 \\ &&0&1\\&&&0}
$$
is nilpotent with $T^2 = 0$.  $x = (0,1,0,0)$ satisfies $Tx \neq 0$, but $\{Tx\}$ fails to span the image of $T$, which is $2$-dimensional.

Of course, we still have a satisfactory direct complement, namely the span of $\{(1,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$.

---

It seems that, in this step, the author is *actually* considering the restriction of $T$ to $V_1$, which is the span of $\{x,Tx,\dots,T^{m-1}x\}$.  With this adjustment, the claim makes sense.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I'm missunderstanding something, could you tell me if there is some difference between $ran(T)$ and $Im(T)$? Because it actually uses the notation $ran(T)$, which I assumed to be the same as $Im(T)$. The proof I'm talking about is this: http://users.math.msu.edu/users/shapiro/pubvit/Downloads/CycNilp/CycNilp.pdf

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should write down the part of the proof instead of copyng the link, I will edit thequestion

Comment: Your interpretation of the notation is correct.  There's something else

Comment: See my latest edit